# Can two players be assigned the same monster role in Monster Seeking Monster?

Tags: jackbox-party-pack-4

At the start of a round in *Monster Seeking Monster*, when players are given their secret role, is it possible for two players to be assigned the same monster role?

To clarify, I am aware that Vampires, Zombies, and Werewolves can infect other players through dating. However, I’m specifically asking if two players can be *assigned* the same role.

So for example: If one player were revealed to be a Leprechaun, is it possible for there to be a second Leprechaun?

Answer (score 1):

Nope; every game will assign each player a unique role (perhaps to make it more interesting instead of just having multiple leprechauns or witches, thus balancing it out a bit more)